# Passing a conditional statement when pushing viewControllers using storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say that I have view controller Origin and Destination. I would like to declare something like:

```
//origin.m file

-(void)pushNextView {


    self.conditional = YES;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDestination" sender:self];

}
```

Where I have set my conditional as:

```
//origin .h file
@propery BOOL conditional;
```

Now in my Destination view controller I'd like to set a conditional based on the property that I've set in my origin:

```
// destination .m file
#import "OriginViewController.h"

OriginViewController *origin = [OriginViewController alloc] init];

if (origin.conditional == YES){

self.navigationItem.hidesbackbutton = YES;

}else{

// Do Nothing    

}
```

for some reason this conditional statement does not work. Does this have to do anything with storyboards?

Comment: Like that it can't work. You alloc/init a NEW `OriginViewcontroller`. It's `.conditional` property will be `NO` at this point - always. You would have to check the reference to the original `OriginViewcontroller` (the sender). Or better yet, do it like described in one of the answers, by passing the value to the destination viewController in `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 1):

With the setup you seem to have it would be most easy to do this. You could directly access destination.hidesbackbutton when executing the segue:

```
//in origin.m
-(void) prepareForSegue.... {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"identifierString"]) {
       DestinationVC *destination = (DestinationVC*)[segue destinationViewController];
       destination.hidesbackbutton = self.conditional; //you can set the .hidesbackbutton property here directly, no need for another property, if your setup is just as simple as in the given example
    }
 }
```

Like this, the destination doesn't check the origin's state and then set it's state, instead the origin just sets the destination's state.
You can do it both ways, but this way is more common.

Of course `hidesbackbutton` has to be a public property declared in `DestinationVC` .h file. 
And as already mentioned, it should really be `hidesBackbutton` Or `hidesBackButton`.

(This all assumes that the class of your DestinationViewController is called `DestinationVC`)

Comment: This is even better than my solution, as far as it is that simple. If the `conditional` state is more complex, I would handle any effects in the `viewDidLoad` (or `viewWillAppear`) of the destination VC.

Comment: And `hidesBackButton` is a valid property of `navigationItem` (as long as it's spelled correctly of course). Maybe you want to edit that? (`destination.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = self.conditional`)

Comment: Good catch. +1 Maybe he does mean navigationItem

Answer (score 0):

Two things: `hidesbackbutton` looks like there's some camelCase missing. This should at least give a warning, doesn't it?

Also from an architectural point of view, I would not ask for the condition. Pass the state to the destination view controller and implement a `BOOL` variable there.

Draft:

```
// origin.m
- (void)prepareForSegue... 
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:"yourIdentifier"]) {
        [(XYZViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setConditional:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the state from your main controller to destination controller where you should handle this View state like and you have to define

```
//destination.h file
@propery BOOL conditional;
```

so when you push the controller from main you can set the destination controller view state in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (origin.conditional == YES) {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Now you have a `conditional` property in the destination view controller but still ask for the bool in the origin VC? Where does `origin` in the `viewDidLoad` come from? This does not make any sense.

Comment: Not in original controller its in destination so that it could be initialise and used in viewDidLoad